# reformatting `GCI IIS:\SSLBindings` to avoid truncation

Tags: powershell, iis-10

There are 8 IIS sites on my Windows 2016 server. 6 are covered by the same multi-SAN certificate and 2 have different certificates.

`GCI IIS:\SSLBindings` truncates the list with an ellipsis:

```
    IP Address          Port   Host Name        Store            Sites
    ----------          ----   ---------        -----            -----
                        443                     CentralCertStore QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM
                                                                 QA.ARIBUYDIRECT.COM
                                                                 QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.CA
                                                                 QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.COM
                                                                 QA.ARITRUCKDIRECT.COM
                                                                 ...
    0.0.0.0             443                     WebHosting       QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM
```

Each site in the first group has an SSL binding for *:443:*hostname* -- i.e., all IPs, port 443, require SNI and hostname is specified.  The last binding is the default binding with SNI not required and no hostname specified, used for old browsers not supporting SNI.

The output I would really like to see is this, formatted nicely for email reporting:

```
    IP Address          Port   Host Name (SNI)          Store            SiteName
    ----------          ----   ---------                -----            -----
    *                   443    QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM     CentralCertStore QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM
    *                   443    QA.ARIBUYDIRECT.COM      CentralCertStore QA.ARIBUYDIRECT.COM
    *                   443    QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.CA    CentralCertStore QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.CA
    *                   443    QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.COM   CentralCertStore QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.COM
    *                   443    QA.ARITRUCKDIRECT.COM    CentralCertStore QA.ARITRUCKDIRECT.COM
    *                   443    QA.VR.ARITRUCKDIRECT.COM CentralCertStore QA.VR.ARITRUCKDIRECT.COM
    *                   443    OPSSCQA.ARIFLEET.COM     CentralCertStore OPS -SC- QA
    0.0.0.0             443    -none-                   WebHosting       QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM
```

I've been hacking away at the PowerShell script, trying to overcome warnings about being unable to change `$null` into a string, or an integer into a string, etc., etc. So I'm taking a step back and asking if there's any obvious way to do this that I'm overlooking.

As an example, here's something I tried. It displays the sitename only, and there are no headers.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> dir iis:\sslbindings |%{ 
    $x = $_; $paths = $x.Sites |%{ $_.ItemXPath.Split("'")[1]}; 
    Add-Member -inputobject $_ -membertype NoteProperty -Name "SiteName" -Value $paths; 
    $_.SiteName } |FT
QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM
QA.ARIBUYDIRECT.COM
QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.CA
QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.COM
QA.ARITRUCKDIRECT.COM
QA.VR.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM
OPS -SC- QA
ARIXSSQA
QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM
```

---

EDIT: Results from @thepip3r's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60324914/864696) attempt. (Possibly i will remove this edit later, since it doesn't really add to the question, but lets me give a well-formatted response to thepip3r's answer)

as given:

```
IpAddress    : 
Port         : 443
Hostname_SNI : 
Store        : CentralCertStore
Site         : {QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM, QA.ARIBUYDIRECT.COM, QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.CA, QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.COM...}

IpAddress    : 0.0.0.0
Port         : 443
Hostname_SNI : 0.0.0.0
Store        : WebHosting
Site         : QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM
```

when FT is added to pipeline:

```
IpAddress Port Hostname_SNI Store            Site                                                                                         
--------- ---- ------------ -----            ----                                                                                         
           443              CentralCertStore {QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM, QA.ARIBUYDIRECT.COM, QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.CA, QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.COM...}
0.0.0.0    443 0.0.0.0      WebHosting       QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## BETTER ANSWER

`Get-WebBinding` produces a far better solution than `IIS:\WebBindings`.

```
 Get-WebBinding -Protocol https `
   |%{ 
      $bi = $_.bindingInformation.Split(":");
      [PsCustomObject]@{
        'IpAddress' = $bi[0]
        'Port' = $bi[1]
        'Hostname_SNI' = $bi[2]
        Store = $( if ($_.sslFlags -eq 3) {"CentralCertStore"} else {$_.certificatestorename} )
        SiteName = $_.ItemXPath.split("'")[1]
      }
    } |ft
```

Results:

```
IpAddress     Port Hostname_SNI            Store            SiteName               
---------     ---- ------------            -----            --------               
*             443                          WebHosting       QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM   
*             443  qa.ariautodirect.com    CentralCertStore QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM   
*             443  qa.aribuydirect.com     CentralCertStore QA.ARIBUYDIRECT.COM    
*             443  qa.aridealerdirect.ca   CentralCertStore QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.CA  
*             443  qa.aridealerdirect.com  CentralCertStore QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.COM 
*             443  qa.aritruckdirect.com   CentralCertStore QA.ARITRUCKDIRECT.COM  
*             443  qa.vr.ariautodirect.com CentralCertStore QA.VR.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM
*             443  OPSSCQA.ARIFLEET.COM    CentralCertStore OPS -SC- QA            
10.220.100.98 443  arixssqa.arifleet.com   CentralCertStore ARIXSSQA
```

---

## PREVIOUS ANSWER

Thanks to 2 things I learned from [the answer by @thepip3r](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60324914/864696) (`Split-Path -Leaf` and `[pscustomobject]@{...}`) , I have surmounted the **formatting** problems. The blank Hostname_SNI problem remains and is due to the folding of the bindings. I guess because each of the bindings uses *:443, SNI, and CCS, it folds them together. It's still a little unexplained because those bindings actually have hostnames.  But I'm happy enough with this for now.

```
import-module webadministration
dir iis:\sslbindings `
 |%{ $Binding = $_
     $Binding.Sites.ItemXPath |%{ $_.split("'")[1] } `
     |% { 
        [pscustomobject]@{
            'IpAddress'    = $( $ip = $Binding.IpAddress.IpAddressToString; if ([String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ip)) { "*" } else { $ip } )
            'Port'         = $Binding.Port
            'Hostname_SNI' = $( $h = ($Binding.PSPath | Split-Path -Leaf).Split('!')[0]; if ([String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($h)) { "--none--" } else {$h} )
            'Store'        = $Binding.Store
            'SiteName'     = $_
        }
     }
 } |ft
```

Output:

```
IpAddress Port Hostname_SNI Store            SiteName               
--------- ---- ------------ -----            --------               
*          443 --none--     CentralCertStore QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM   
*          443 --none--     CentralCertStore QA.ARIBUYDIRECT.COM    
*          443 --none--     CentralCertStore QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.CA  
*          443 --none--     CentralCertStore QA.ARIDEALERDIRECT.COM 
*          443 --none--     CentralCertStore QA.ARITRUCKDIRECT.COM  
*          443 --none--     CentralCertStore QA.VR.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM
*          443 --none--     CentralCertStore OPS -SC- QA            
*          443 --none--     CentralCertStore ARIXSSQA               
0.0.0.0    443 0.0.0.0      WebHosting       QA.ARIAUTODIRECT.COM
```

Comment: Awesome--glad you were able to work it out. Sorry I couldn't help more--stupid high security environments!  Also, looking at your code, makes me lament the lack of a built-in ternary operator!!!  Best of luck with the report!

Answer (score 1):

First try:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$SslBindings = @(gci IIS:\SslBindings)

if ($SslBindings.count -gt 0) {
    foreach ($Binding in $SslBindings) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            'IpAddress'    = $Binding.IpAddress.IpAddressToString
            'Port'         = $Binding.Port
            'Hostname_SNI' = ($Binding.PSPath | Split-Path -Leaf).Split('!')[0]
            'Store'        = $Binding.Store
            'Site'         = $Binding.Sites.Value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite a win yet. Here's what it outputs: https://pastebin.com/raw/QBVBMhfa  In addition to the group containing all the sitenames in an array that is the value of the Site array, PSPath also came out blank, again probably because SSLBindings is folding the binding on each site into one, for reasons I don't really understand.

Comment: @RossPresser, it's all about the underlying data types of each--where each component of data is stored in the tree-structured object that is each $Binding instance and what type of data they are (e.g. string, int, array, collection, etc.).  Unfortunately, I only have a single Web Server with a single site to test this against.  Additionally, I can't access pastebin from my corp environment so I can't see the screen shot.  I'll respond as soon as I can when I can get to a device that can see the screenshot (or whatever it is)

Comment: update: I copied the plain-text content of pastebin into my question so you can see it. And I thank you very much for your try. I've already learned something I didn't know (`Split-Path -Leaf` FTW)

Comment: upvoting because you helped me reach the formatting solution I wanted!